# ASP.NET CORE Ajax post additional paramaters with view model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

In my project (ASP.NET Core 2.2. MVC) I'm trying to do an ajax post with additional parameters to the view model. The form on the page has an id='frmMain'.

My js looks like this:

```
//post
var data = {
    model: $("#frmMain").serialize(),
    passtest: 'test'
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
    //alert('form was submitted');
}
}).done(function (result) {

    if (result.status === "success") {

        //some code here
    }
    } else {
        //some code here
    }
});
```

My controller actions looks like this:

```cs
public IActionResult DoSomething(MyModel model, string passtest)
{
    //some action code here
}
```

Now, the post works, but in my controller action only "model" is filled with data. Variable "passtest" is null. Also there is no "passtest" in the "model".

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I found a workaround with filling hidden fields (and adding them to the view model), but plainly passing multiple parameters in the post itself seems more practical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append it to the url using the query notation.

`url = url + '?passtest=' + myVal`

Let's say if your `myVal` includes special characters like `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`

You then want to encode it so they are not parsed as part of the url notation:

`url = url + '?passtest=' + encodeURIComponent(myVal)`

Comment: thank you, this works. Can `myVal` contain special characters like: ' " / \ ? +

Comment: @TheMixy kinda, you'll need to encode the part of the url containing special characters using the `encodeURIComponent(part)` function. I've updated the answer.